# AWK script to sort the list in alphabetical order of usernames in getent passwd

Tags: sorting, awk, pipeline

I am very new to awk and I am trying to sort the fifth group of my usernames which has " Zack e" in alphabetical order. I typed `getent passwd` in my terminal, which are:

```
zack:x:115:120:Zack E:/home/zack:/var/run/bin/bash/false
hp:x:118:7:HPLIP system user:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
armvad:x:3:3:Ezikon Armvad:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
bruh:x:1542:1546:Burh RG:/home/banner:/bin/bash
```

I also tried this approached

```
for i in `sed -e 's/.* \(\d\)*/\1/' passwd.in | sort`; do grep $i passwd.in; done > file_sort.txt
```

But all it did was sort the first group instead of the desired group. How can I combine my approach with an awk script all I know to do in awk is `BEGIN {FS = ":"} $5 == 1000{print $1}`

Is there any way, I can rearrange the tokens so sort can  work, and then put them back in order?

Comment: @tripleee None of the answers in the linked duplicate use awk for sorting. Then again, neither does the tried solution in the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with "just use `sort`" but in any event, the questions are similar enough and the possible answers seem to just about cover it. Maybe add yours as an answer to that question and concur with the duplicate vote rather than have multiple distractingly similar questions with different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why 'awk' when 'sort' may do the job elegantly?

```
sort -t : -k5 myFile.txt
```

or, reversely

```
sort -r -t : -k5 myFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and [`for` scanning order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for sorting at output when the `$5` is unique for each record:

```
$ awk -F: '{a[$5]=$0}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
bruh:x:1542:1546:Burh RG:/home/banner:/bin/bash
armvad:x:3:3:Ezikon Armvad:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
hp:x:118:7:HPLIP system user:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
zack:x:115:120:Zack E:/home/zack:/var/run/bin/bash/false
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F: '{                              # set field delimiter
     a[$5]=$0                             # hash records, use $5 as key
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # set the for traverse order
    for(i in a)                           # use it
        print a[i]                        # output
}' file
```

Since the hash key is `$5` it needs to be unique to avoid collisions. If they are not unique, I guess in this case, where the records are unique, you could:

```
$ awk -F: '{
    a[$0]=$5                              # changed
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"  # changed
    for(i in a)
        print i                           # changed
}' file
```

Then there are of course functions `asort` and `asorti` that sort arrays where as the above examples sorted at output. For example, we expect the $5 not to be unique:

```
$ awk -F: '{
    a[$0]=$5                      # record is unique, $5 is not expected to be
}
END {
    n=asorti(a,b,"@val_str_asc")  # asorti to preserve $0 in b but order from a[] value
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)             # sorted to b, index rewritten from 1..n
        print i, b[i]
}' file
```

Output now:

```
1 bruh:x:1542:1546:Burh RG:/home/banner:/bin/bash
2 armvad:x:3:3:Ezikon Armvad:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
3 hp:x:118:7:HPLIP system user:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
4 zack:x:115:120:Zack E:/home/zack:/var/run/bin/bash/false
```